# Asymptotic expressions for incomplete Gamma

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have an expression below and want to approximate it with a simpler form by taking $d$ to infinity

$$
f(s)=\frac{s^{1/p} \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{p},(d+1)^{-p} s\right)}{p}
$$

Taking `Asymptotic` returns unevaluated.

```
expr = (t^(1/p) Gamma[-(1/p), (1 + d)^-p t])/p ;
Asymptotic[expr, {d, Infinity, 2}]
```

Are there tricks in Mathematica to get a simpler expression for this in the infinite $d$ limit?

```
With[{p = 101/100, d = 10^9},
 expr = (t^(1/p) Gamma[-(1/p), (1 + d)^-p t])/p ;
 Plot[expr, {t, 1, d}, AxesLabel -> {"time", "error"}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `Assumptions -> d > 0 && p > 0 && t > 0` (assuming those are desired restrictions) results in a response from `Asymptotic` (Windows 10, Mathematica 13.2.0.0).

Comment: The 2nd order approximation appears to be `1 + d + ((1 + d)^(1 - p) t)/(-1 + p) + ((1 + d)^(1 - 2 p) t^2)/(2 - 4 p) + ((1 + d)^(1 - 3 p) t^3)/(-6 + 18 p) - t^(1/p) Gamma[(-1 + p)/p]`. And the form for the $k$-th order approximation is $\sum _{i=0}^{k+1} \frac{(-1)^{i+1} t^i (d+1)^{1-i p}}{i! (i p-1)}-t^{1/p} \Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$.

Comment: Asymptotic does produce some result, but it doesn't seem to fit the graph in $0<t<d$ regime which is what I'm trying to find

Comment: Please include your requirements for a good fit.  The following produces a ratio of the true to approximate value from 0.999997 to 1:  `a = With[{k = 6}, -t^(1/p) Gamma[1 - 1/p] + Sum[(-1)^(i + 1) t^i (1 + d)^(1 - i p)/(i! (i p - 1)), {i, 0, k + 1}]]; Plot[expr/a /. {d -> 10^9, p -> 101/100}, {t, 1, 10^9}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First substituting `u -> (1 + d)^-p t` and assuming `u->0` for `d->Infinity`
Mathematica (v12.2 Windows11) evaluates

```
expr = (t^(1/p) Gamma[-(1/p), (1 + d)^-p t])/p
zw = Asymptotic[Gamma[-(1/p), u], {u, 0, 3}]  
asy = t^(1/p)/p zw /. u -> (1 + d)^-p t // Simplify(* third order asymptote*)
```

$\frac{t^{\frac{1}{p}} \left(\frac{1}{6} p \left(\frac{t^3
   (d+1)^{-3 p}}{3 p-1}+\frac{3 t^2 (d+1)^{-2 p}}{1-2
   p}+\frac{6 t (d+1)^{-p}}{p-1}+6\right) \left(t
   (d+1)^{-p}\right)^{-1/p}+\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)}{p}$

```
Block[{p = 101/100, d = 10^9}, 
Plot[{expr, asy}, {t, 1, d}, AxesLabel -> {"time", "error"},PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, All}[[-1]],PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]]
```

[image]

**But** initial assumption `u->0` doesn't hold for `z=O[d]`! That's why approximation  applies only to `t=o[d]`!

Hope it's what you're looking for!

Comment: ah, thanks, indeed, I was looking for something tight in the range of $t=o(d)$

Comment: background for this problem is given [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)